# UITableViewController with different Cell sizes and Cell content in Storyboard

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout, uikit, tableview

I want to make a `UITableViewController` with different Cell sizes and different content of the cells.

For example:

[image: Example Storyboard]

Is there a way to use `AutoLayout` within the `Storyboard` to define the different sizes of the `TableViewCells`? What would be the best way to define the content (a `UIView` with content on it) of the `TableViewCells`?

Comment: you can use different cell with dfferent idenifier .

Comment: I know, I'm also doing that to say wich cell is from which custom cell-class. But I can't change the size of the cells.

Comment: please do clear what you want to ? if you tried any things then add code here .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change the cells of the UITableView, you have 2 options:

**Option A (best)** is to use Autosizing TableView Cells with Autolayout Constraints.

To use option A, you need to make sure your cell contentview has clear top & bottom constraints to all your UI elements in the content View (see my image here) as an example:

[image: Autosizing UITableViewCell]

The Title UILabel has a top space to the superview (Cell ContentView) and a vertical spacing with the SubTitle.
The SubTitle has also a bottom space constraint to the superview (Cell ContentView).

This allows the cell to be autoresized as my UI elements have top & bottom constraints to the content view.

Final step to enable the autosizing is to set these 2 properties in your UITableView:

```
self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 60.0;
self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
```

The `estimatedRowHeight` value should be as close as you can guess to the real size, this helps speed up calculations a bit.

**Option B** is to add the `- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;` delegate to your UIViewController.

There you should be manually providing the height of the cell.
If you are using just 2 different cells with 2 fixed heights, you can use option B as well and there you add a logic to detect the cell and return the height...

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    if ([cell isKindOfClass:[MyCustomCellTypeAClass class]]) {
        return 44;
    }
    else {
        return 100;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using auto-layout, height will be calculated using constraints (if you set them properly); and you have to use delegate method as following -

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use storyboard? do your mean like this? 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L8N9F.png)

Maybe i should provided a demo(StackOverFlowQuestions02) to be clear. for more details --->link:

https://github.com/tingxins/StackOverFlowQuestions

I believe that running demo and you will get it.