# Constraint Bounds ios Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview

Im having some serious problems with my story board UIImage view and labels. All i want is for my constraints to work out and look exactly how I have it set up in my story board.

**UI looks like this**
[image]

**Story Board**
[image]

All i want is for my UI is to look exactly how I have it in the story board.

**Problem 1:** Cell does not show complete length.

**Problem 2:** I dont know how to set the constraint for the messageLabel to work properly for self dynamic cells. The code is correct because I can get it to work but all my constraints are messed up and I dont know how to properly set them up.

-I am new to swift

**Code(took out non-relevant functions)**

```
import UIKit
import Foundation


struct postStruct {
    let username : String!
    let message : String!
    let photoURL : String!
}



class GeneralChatroom: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var messageTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    var generalRoomDataArr = [postStruct]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()




        self.tableView.dataSource = self
        self.tableView.delegate = self

        tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44
        tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension



        let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
        //let userID = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid




    }








    }



    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return generalRoomDataArr.count // your number of cell here
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {




        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")

        //Set username label to display username
        let usernameLabel = cell?.viewWithTag(1) as! UILabel
        usernameLabel.text = generalRoomDataArr[indexPath.row].username

        //Set message label to display message
        let messageLabel = cell?.viewWithTag(2) as! UILabel
        messageLabel.text = generalRoomDataArr[indexPath.row].message
        messageLabel.numberOfLines = 0

        //initialize UI Profile Image
        let imageView = cell?.viewWithTag(3) as! UIImageView

        //Make Porfile Image Cirlce
        imageView.layer.cornerRadius = imageView.frame.size.width/2
        imageView.clipsToBounds = true

        //Loading and change of Usesrs profile image on chat cell
        let userProfileChatImage = generalRoomDataArr[indexPath.row].photoURL

        //Load profile image(on cell) with URL & Alamofire Library
        let downloadURL = NSURL(string: userProfileChatImage!)
        imageView.af_setImage(withURL: downloadURL as! URL)

        // your cell coding
        return cell!
    }
```

Comment: [My answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40607085/312312) should point you to the correct solution. You need to add top and bottom constraints to the cell and all  the ui elements in between

Comment: What do you mean by auto resizing. I tried sudgested constraints but that is a failure. Ive been playing with this for a while and I cant seem to figure it out.